# Write a log when an object is created with postUpdate($object) / Sonata & Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, monolog

I've created an admin interface using Symfony and Sonata.
For the moment, everything is working fine.

Now, I want to test how the hooks are working, according to this tutorial : http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/saving_hooks.html
For the moment, I just want to test how this method works.
What I would like to do, is write a log everything I create an object via my admin interface.
Here's the first part of my AdminClass code (working) :

```
namespace AAA\AdminBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;

class CompteAdmin extends Admin
{
// Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('prenom')
        ->add('nom')
        ->add('fonction')
    ;
}
```

And here's the following part (not working) :

```
public function postPersist($logger)
{
    $logger = $this->get('logger');
    $logger->err('Une erreur est survenue');
}
```

When trying to add an object, I have this log error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method INERIS\AdminBundle\Admin\CompteAdmin::get()
```

or

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method INERIS\AdminBundle\Entity\Compte::err()
```

depends if I comment lines or not.

To write into log, Symfony use Monolog. I followed this tutorial http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog.html, but obviously I'm doint it wrong because the $logger should be declared into a controller, not there.

I don't know how to figure out then.

Maybe there is an add missing at the beginning of the AdminClass to enable Monolog.
Maybe my function postPersist took the wrong object.

Any tips would be helpful ;)

**Edit :** Resolved, check the post below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
 calls:
   - [ setLogger, ['%logger%'] ]
```

to admin's service definition (usually in admin.yml) and add method to *Admin class

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger

....

public function setLogger(Logger $logger) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

after that you can log as usual

```
$this->logger->err('Une erreur est survenue');
```

**UPDATE**

After discussion in comment's this is the correct way of getting logger in *Admin class:

```
public function postPersist($logger)
{
    $logger = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('logger');
    $logger->err('Une erreur est survenue');
}
```

Looks like SonataAdminBundle does not uses standard service injection/resolving system

Comment: Hmhmh, but with such method, I lose the postPersist function ? That was the first idea of my post. By the way, I've an error while trying your method. The error comes from the call : The service "sonata.admin.compte" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "logger".

Comment: Why do you lose it? You can have it. setLogger function would be called before your method

Comment: run symfony's command "container:debug" in required environment (better to do that in both prod and dev) and in that list you should see "logger" service. if it's not present there, then you need to configure it (i think just add dependency to composer and enable it in AppKernel "new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle()")

Comment: Ok, i'll check it out. Then I'll come back there.

Comment: Ok fine, Monolog is well installed and enabled in Kernel. Result of the debug service : [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
  The service "sonata.admin.compte" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "logger". Did you mean one of these: "debug.errors_logger_listener.class", "data_collector.logger.class", "monolog.logger.c
  lass", "swiftmailer.plugin.messagelogger.class", "doctrine.dbal.logger.chain.class", "doctrine.dbal.logger.profiling.class", "doctrine.dbal.logger.class"? // I guess the error comes from the %logger%

Comment: Did you clear a cache after installing & configuring monolog? Also can you try to use monolog in simple controller ($this->get('logger')->err('Une erreur est survenue');)? If you can use it in controller and can't in Admin class, then I'm not sure how to fix it right now (will check later). If you can't use it in controller, then it means that logger is not properly configured.

Comment: OK, I've found a way. You don't need to use service injection. Just use this code: $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('logger'). I don't know why, but looks like SonataAdminBundle does not uses standard servies

Comment: Hmhmh, so I've erased the injection into admin.yml. Now the code looks like this :     public function setLogger(Logger $logger) {
        $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('logger') 
    }
    public function postPersist($logger)
    {
        $this->$logger->err('Une erreur est survenue');
    } I'm a bit confused right now with this new function o_O

Comment: You need to remove setLogger method and then, please, read my update post

Comment: Ok, that was I was thinking, I'd already deleted it. Now the code is working, thanks. It create a prod.log file into the log folder as expected, even If for the moment I can't open it. Edit : opened the file, everything is working ! Anyway, a big thanks to you :-)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you must get the logger object this way:

```
$logger = $this->getContainer()->get('logger');
```

and add at the beggining this, if that doesn't work:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\LoggerInterface;
```